# Windows 8 tablet running regular exe. How to make things bigger?

Tags: winforms, windows-8, exe, tablet

We want to run our regular **forms applications** on **Windows 8 Pro tablets**. They actually run without any problem, but they look very very **small** on tablet' s screen. The tablet runs under 1024x768 or 1280x800 screen resolutions and that' s all it supports.

1) A solution might be to run our exe application inside another third party exe, so that it becomes possible to **pinch**(in order to zoom in/out) Is it possible and do you know any software like this?

2) In **Android**, there exists [LCDDensity](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.lcddensity&hl=en) like apps, so that people can change the screen resolutions freely. Is there any Windows 8 application that does the same?

3) Any other ideas to achieve this?

Comment: So, did my advice to increase display size helped to solve your problem?

Comment: Playing with text sizes made some controls more usable. Some controls overlapped and distorted, so this did not solved my problem exactly, but it was at least a step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play with Form property AutoScaleMode, set it to DPI.

Comment: We actually don' t want to play with our existing applications. Instead, we need a way to use controls more easily. For example the combo boxes, editboxes, buttons are so small that it is hard to use them.

Comment: Is your text size is already set to 150% and apps still looks small? If not, try to set global OS setting 'display size' to Larger (150%). Here is a [link how to do it](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/make-text-screen-larger-smaller).